# Integral of $e^x/x$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any way to find $\displaystyle\int\frac{e^x}{x}\,dx$? I was told that it cannot be solved in regular manner, but (I am not really sure about this) solution can be found by introducing some additional concept. Can some "trick" be performed as it is done in the case of Gaussian integral?

Comment: do you know integration by parts?

Comment: The Gaussian integral is a definite integral. You want here (I guess) an indefinite integral (a primitive). This is not expressable in terms of elementary functions. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Comment: I want a definite integral, but I don't know how to write it down. It seems that you gave me the link I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), which admits no closed form solution. See [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) and [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29).